# Mosfet identification

Tags: mosfet

What mosfet is this? I know that it's N-Channel but where's the side of Source and Drain? I think, Source it's at right side, because of shifted Gate line... What's the usage of the two opposite diodes?

[image]

Comment: It's a symbol for an N-channel enhancement mosfet. If you dive a bit into mosfets you will learn that drain and source are identical for most mosfets. The diodes are always there, they are an intrinsic part of the device. Any textbook about MOSFETs will explain everything !

Comment: Question should be closed - insufficient research.

Comment: In N-channel MOSFETs diodes should be in reverse 
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran20a.gif?81223b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two diodes exist in any MOSFET (and as @MrBit points out, they actually should be the other way around in an N-channel device), but in most discrete devices, the substrate is shorted to the source, which effectively eliminates the right-hand diode. If the substrate is brought out to a separate terminal, it must be connected to the most negative point in the circuit in order to keep those diodes reverse-biased. (Or the most positive point for a P-channel device.)

Comment: With shorted substrate-source, right-hand diode seems to be like as show in the circuit but left-hand diode should be inverted.

Comment: @MrBit: No, as you correctly pointed out in your comment on the question, they both should be turned around. Although the short across the right-hand diode makes its orientation moot.

Comment: How shorted substrate to source affect to the left-hand diode?

Comment: The short does not affect the diode, but the diode affects the circuit operation: The drain can never go more than one diode drop below the source. If it does, the diode conducts current regardless of whether the gate is active.

Comment: as you notice in your answer the schematic about diodes it's wrong? Or substrate-source shorting affect this orientation?